# OpenFileDialog does not appear

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, openfiledialog

I have this DataGridView and I want every time you click on the *Browse From File...*  an openFileDialog to open.

[image]

Made this so far but it does not work.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   string bbb = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
   if (bbb == "Browse From File...")
   {
       openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();
   }
```

Tried also these but nothing:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex.Equals = "Browse From File...")
if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells = "Browse From File...")   
if ((string)dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value == "Browse From File...")
if (dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells["Browse From File..."].Value.ToString() == "Browse From File...")
           {
               //openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();
           }
```

Comment: Have you tried in debug if event is fireing?

Comment: What does bbb equal in your first example when you debug it? Have you tried getting ((DataGridViewCell)sender).Value?

Comment: debug and tell us the value of bbbin this line: if (bbb == "Browse From File...")

Comment: @piotr When I do _Step into_ it does not enter the CellValueChanged method when I click on _Browse From File..._

Comment: @davide I toggled breakpoints in this method and the program never stops to go to the breakpoint. I suppose the method CellValueChanged is never fired.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to catch the event where the controls from the datagrid are shown (*EditingControlsShowing*) and add SelectionChanged handler on the combo box.

Something like this:

```
    private void dataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control is ComboBox)
        {
            ComboBox cellComboBox = (ComboBox)e.Control;
            if (cellComboBox != null)
            {
                cellComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cellComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    void cellComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl comboBox = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
        if (comboBox != null)
        {
            if (String.Compare(comboBox.Text, "Browse From File...") == 0)
            {
                openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

In order to add the event handler to the grid: Go to design view for your form and right click on the grid. Click properties in the context menu. In the properties window click on the Events button (the lightning image) and search the EditingControlShowing entry. Double click the empty space to add the event handler. In the page code behind you'll see an empty method similar with *dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing*, in that method copy/paste the code from the above method. Beside that also copy/paste in the same source file the second method cellComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: **Does not work.** Doesn't fire non of this methods. I toggled breakpoints and they didn't stop the program.

Comment: I've just tested this and it works for me. Did you add the event handler to the data grid: this.dataGridView.EditingControlShowing += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(this.dataGridView_EditingControlShowing);

Comment: where should I put this ? I added it in a button method and it showed me errors.

Comment: Error:`The event 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.EditingControlShowing' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=`

Comment: Which is exactly is the event handler ? Error accurs when I paste this:                          `this.dataGridView.EditingControlShowing += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(this.dataGrid‌​View_EditingControlShowing);`

Comment: @george don't paste that line anymore, try to do as i described in my edit

Answer (score 0):

Is it what it's supposed to be?

```
if (bbb.equals("Browse From File..."))
```